# pip install selenium - 'Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'

Tags: python, windows, selenium, pip, installation

I'm trying to install `selenium` via `pip`, however it fails under the following Environment Error:

```
Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden
```

I've searched for solutions but none that I understand have worked so I need some help

```
(base) C:\>pip install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'))': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'))': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'))': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'))': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'))': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

Comment: are you behind proxy? can you share the entire traceback

Comment: Updated to include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org selenium
```

If the above doesn't work, can you try the following :

1. Download `selenium` from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/)
2. Go the the folder `selenium/py`
3. Run the command `python setup.py install`

Comment: I'm afraid the same outcome

Comment: are you facing this issue with any other libraries

Comment: Everything else I've installed has had no issue

Comment: Hi Jeril, It looks like a File is not in that download, getAttribute.js withing the Webdriver\remote folder.